# Why doesn't my for loop pass values?

Tags: java, android, xml, for-loop

I have created a method to loop through a file with 4-items and generate class obj
Resource Template below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<part1prayer>   
    <item> 
         <title> </title>
         <arabictext> </arabictext>
         <transliteration> </transliteration>
         <tanslanguage> </tanslanguage>
         <translation> </translation>
    </item>
</part1prayer>
```

For some reason this method keeps returning last Item item[3] four times  not `item[0]`, `item[1]` and `item[2]`

However, if I pass the Value manually at this line **`nNode = nList.item(temp);`** i.e. replace `temp` with 2, it will return item 2 four times.

```
public ArrayList<PrayerDataProperties> readAssetFile2(String fileName) {

  ArrayList<PrayerDataProperties> listOfPrayers = null;

  try {
    listOfPrayers = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream inputstream = null;
    Node nNode = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    inputstream = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputstream);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(ITEM);

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
      nNode = nList.item(temp);

      if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        PrayerDataProperties prayerData = new PrayerDataProperties();
        prayerData.setArabicTxt(eElement.getElementsByTagName(ARABIC_TEXT)
            .item(0).getTextContent());
        prayerData.setTransliterationTxt(eElement
            .getElementsByTagName(TRANSLITERATION).item(0).getTextContent());
        prayerData.setTransLangTxt(eElement
            .getElementsByTagName(TRANS_LANGUAGE).item(0).getTextContent());
        prayerData.setTranslationTxt(eElement
            .getElementsByTagName(TRANSLATION).item(0).getTextContent());

        listOfPrayers.add(prayerData);
      }// End if

    }// End for

  }// End try

  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }// End catch

  return listOfPrayers;

}// End of readAssetFile2

public class PrayerListCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;
private ArrayList<PrayerDataProperties> listsOfPrayer;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private PrayerDataProperties prayerDataProperties;

// Empty Constructor
public PrayerListCustomAdapter()
{

}// End Empty Constructor

public PrayerListCustomAdapter(Context acontext,             ArrayList<PrayerDataProperties> prayerLists)
{
    this.context = acontext;
    this.listsOfPrayer = prayerLists;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(acontext);

}//End of Constructor

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listsOfPrayer.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listsOfPrayer.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return listsOfPrayer.indexOf(position);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View customView = convertView;
    // Inflate the View if Empty
    if (customView == null)
    {
        customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.prayer_list_template,        null);
        // Attach View to View inflated and ViewGroup
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        // Instantiate Views
        holder.arabicTxt =   (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_arabic_txt);
        holder.transliterationTxt = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_transliteration_txt);
        holder.transLanguageTxt = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_translang_txt);
        holder.translationTxt = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_translation_txt);

        customView.setTag(holder);

    }//End if
    else
    {
        // Call The View already Inflated
        holder = (ViewHolder)customView.getTag();
    }//End else

    // Pass Data to Each View
    prayerDataProperties = (PrayerDataProperties)getItem(position);

    holder.arabicTxt.setText(prayerDataProperties.getArabicTxt());
      holder.transliterationTxt.setText(prayerDataProperties.getTransliterationTxt());
    holder.transLanguageTxt.setText(prayerDataProperties.getTransLangTxt());
    holder.translationTxt.setText(prayerDataProperties.getTranslationTxt());

    return customView;
}//End of getView

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView arabicTxt, transliterationTxt, translationTxt,     transLanguageTxt;
}

}// End of PrayerListCustomAdapter
```

Comment: No meant to show the items template.

Comment: It adds item[3] four times. Sorry Guys I am new on here.

Comment: @Want2bExpert Welcome to Stack Overflow! I understand that you are new, but here we prefer that people [edit] their questions rather than replying in the comments with their updates and clarifications. Please do so now.

Comment: @durron597 I am glad to join the community of Experts to improve. I have editted as requested thanks for your support Guys

Comment: is it possible that the length of nList is greater than 4? If so, you might be writing the correct data in, then writing over it repeatedly with the last piece of data. make sure that nList has no empty nodes that would inflate the length and break your for loop.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code that you are using to check the result?

Comment: @innoSPG the result return Lists for my CustomAdapter class to populate Fragment. Do you want me to add the Fragment and CustomAdapter Classes?

Comment: One possibility might be that the method that is populating the fragment is doing something nasty. Like doing a loop with index that is not changing. Also double check the data in the file to make sure they are really different one from each other.

Comment: @innoSPG I have had a look many times can't seem to find anything. I ran the same method in Netbean IDE, it printed out all items as expected. Please have a look at my Adapter class maybe I am doing something wrong there perhaps?

Comment: Where is the adapter class?

Comment: Not Adding, Trying to Indent it as requested on here, I can quickly email it to you if you dont mind?

Comment: @durron597 PrayerDataProperties is a DataModel for each Item

Comment: @durron597 Oh sorry, they are static variables? could that be the issue?

Comment: I did not read stackoverflow for a day. Anyway, I am glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the fields in `PrayerDataProperties` aren't static. If they are, then all instances will have the same value, and they get overwritten as you read in the XML.

If those fields do have the `static` keyword, remove them, and it should fix your issue.

Comment: How I missed the logic behind static effects on variables that is dynamic is surprising. Almost at the point of breaking my phone!!. Thanks. I have ticked it as Answered.